# What is the difference between operator groups and group actions?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have always thought that operator groups and group actions are two names for the same thing.

Now I have noticed that they have different codomains.
Actually I am still confused, why are they defined this way?

Comment: I view them as "dual" concepts. Group actions are about groups acting on sets, and operator groups are sets acting on groups. Of course, there are conditions that need to be satisfied about these types of actions. Common examples include groups acting on themselves (group action), and Aut$(G)$ acting on $G$ (operator group).

Comment: so they are identical when the set we consider is a group?

Comment: Maybe in special cases. With group actions, we want $1$ to fix every element and composition of actions to be composition of group elements. For operator groups, we want the set $\Omega$ to act in such a way that the map $g\mapsto g^\omega$ is an endomorphism for every fixed $\omega\in\Omega$. In particular, $1^\omega=1$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, so they're not identical in general.